# Getting the Image to display in a Custom ButtonImage Control c#

Tags: image, button

I'm new to c# and i'm trying to create a ButtonImage Control. I've managed to get most of the code to work including TextAlignment and image resource selection, but the image won't display. I've tried adding TextImageRelation property as well as the ImageAlignment property to no effect - not even sure if I've done everything correctly. I've spent hours searching MSDN and the internet, please help, tnx. Heres the code:

```
namespace ImageButton
{
    //[System.ComponentModel.DefaultBindingProperty("ButtonText")]
    public partial class ImageButton : UserControl
    {
        private String name = "btn1";
        private String btnText = "Button1";
        private TextImageRelation textImage = TextImageRelation.Overlay;
        private ContentAlignment alignmentValue = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        private ContentAlignment imageAlignmentValue = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;

        public ImageButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //
        // Properties
        //
        [Description("Sets the Text Label"),
         Category("Custom")]
        public String ButtonText
        {
            get
            {
                return btnText;
            }
            set
            {
                btnText = value;
                btn1.Text = btnText;
            }
        }
        [Description("Sets the Button Image"),
         Category("Custom")]
        public Image Image
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Description("Specifies the relationship of text to Image."),
         Category("Custom")]
        public TextImageRelation TextImageRelation { 
            get{
                return textImage;
            }
            set{
                textImage =value;
                btn1.TextImageRelation = textImage;
            }
        }
        [Category("Custom"),
         Description("Specifies the alignment of text.")]
        public ContentAlignment TextAlignment
        {
            get
            {
                return alignmentValue;
            }
            set
            {
                alignmentValue = value;
                btn1.TextAlign = alignmentValue;
                //Invalidate();
            }
        }
        [Category("Custom"),
         Description("Specifies the alignment of text.")]
        public ContentAlignment ImageAlignment
        {
            get
            {
                return imageAlignmentValue;
            }
            set
            {
                imageAlignmentValue = value;
                btn1.ImageAlign = imageAlignmentValue;
            }
        }    
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            StringFormat style = new StringFormat();
            style.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            switch (alignmentValue)
            {
                case ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft:
                    style.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                    break;
                case ContentAlignment.MiddleRight:
                    style.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                    break;
                case ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
                    style.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    break;
            }
            // Call the DrawString method of the System.Drawing class to write   
            // text. Text and ClientRectangle are properties inherited from
            // Control.
            e.Graphics.DrawString(
                Text,
                Font,
                new SolidBrush(ForeColor),
                ClientRectangle, style);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

instead of:

```
    public Image Image{ get; set;}
```

as other ppl have suggested, I used

```
    public Image Image{
        get { return image; }
        set
        {
            image = value;
            btn1.Image = image;
        }
    }
```